# How to handle 204 response in Retrofit using Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit

I'm using [retrofit: ^3.0.1+1](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit) and [retrofit_generator: ^4.0.3+1](https://pub.dev/packages/retrofit_generator) with Flutter and Dart.

I have a Retrofit method as such:

```
  @GET(ApiDashboard.urlFaults)
  Future<HttpResponse<List<FaultModel>>> fetchFaults({
    @Query(ApiDashboard.queryKey) required String key,
    @Query(ApiDashboard.queryFaultStartTime) required String startTime,
    @Query(ApiDashboard.queryFaultEndTime) required String endTime,
  });
```

This call returns an HTTP 204 No Content response, which causes a crash in Retrofit:

> DioError [`DioErrorType.other`]: type '`String`' is not a subtype of type
> '`List<dynamic>?`' in type cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment [Retrofit doesn't support responses with 200 and 204 on the same call](https://github.com/trevorwang/retrofit.dart/issues/310). The workaround is to use `dynamic` as the result and then deserialize it yourself like the following.

```dart
@GET(ApiDashboard.urlFaults)
Future<HttpResponse<dynamic>> fetchFaults({
  @Query(ApiDashboard.queryKey) required String key,
  @Query(ApiDashboard.queryFaultStartTime) required String startTime,
  @Query(ApiDashboard.queryFaultEndTime) required String endTime,
});
```

Usage is going to be something like:

```dart
final response = apiDashboard.fetchFaults(...);
if (response.statusCode == 204) return null;
return (response.data as List).map(item => FaultModel.fromJson(data));
```